# React query invalidateQueries partial match not working

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a few `useQuery()` calls in my react component like this:

```
const {...} = useQuery(["person.getAll", ....
const {...} = useQuery(["person.getCounts", ....
```

Then later in a click event after some DELETE/POST request is finished I try to invalidate above queries:

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries("person");
```

But it does not trigger the re-fetch.
I thought it's some state management issues from my part but then I tried invalidating a specific query like

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries("person.getAll");
```

and it works fine..

Is partial query key matching not working in react-query ?

Comment: Have you tried `invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['person'] })`?

Answer (score 6):

React-Query invalidation works off based array prefixes, not string prefixes.

Your `useQuery` calls should look like this:

```js
const {...} = useQuery(["person", "getAll", ....
const {...} = useQuery(["person", "getCounts", ....
```

And then you `invalidateQueries` call will work, with a slight change:

```js
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
  queryKey: ["person"]
}); // invalidate all query keys which start with "person"

queryClient.invalidateQueries(["person"]); // this also works
```

Alternative, if you are locked into your current syntax, you can accomplish the same using a predicate:

```js
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
  predicate: query =>
    query.queryKey[0].startsWith("person"),
})
```

But this breaks the React-Query convention.

Comment: Reason for -1? Please let it be pettiness for the bounty lol

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Someone is giving all answers here -1. Welcome to Earth.

Answer (score 4):

If you see the last example in the [`invalidateQueries`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation#query-matching-with-invalidatequeries) docs, it provides an option for maximum granularity

> If you find yourself wanting even more granularity, you can pass a `predicate` function to the `invalidateQueries` method. This function will receive each Query instance from the query cache and allow you to return true or false for whether you want to invalidate that query:

So, for your scenario the following should work

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
  predicate: query =>
    query.queryKey[0].startsWith('person'),
})
```

Comment: An invaluable feature for edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of how you are structuring the `queryKey` array. The first constant value of your `queryKey` array is a whole string, based on what you provided the partial matching won't work if you try to invalidate the queries based on just a part of that string. For this to work, you'd need to structure the `queryKey` array like so:

```
const {...} = useQuery(["person", "getAll", ....
const {...} = useQuery(["person", "getCounts", ....
```

Now the invalidation should work as expected because it's matching all queries that start with `"person"` in their query key:

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries(["person"]);
```

[Reference of this on the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation#query-matching-with-invalidatequeries)